# Получить значение свойства товара

Tags: битрикс

При многоязычности основанной на пользовательских свойствах каталога, во многих компонентах отсутствует штатная возможность получить доп. свойства товара в $arResult (например в bitrix:sale.personal.order.detail). Подскажите пожалуйста универсальный запрос, который будет работать из разных мест сайта, по выводу свойства PROPERTY_EN_NAME, при условии что я знаю id инфоблока и элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно получить свойство элемента инфоблока по `ID` элемента и `CODE` свойства

```
$elementId = 123;
$arSelect = ['IBLOCK_ID', 'ID'];
$arFilter = ['ID' => $elementId];
$ibElement = CIBlockElement::GetList([], $arFilter, $arSelect)->GetNextElement();
$ibElProp = $ibElement->GetProperties([], ['CODE' => 'EN_NAME']);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сделал на этой основе такой код и все работает!) <?php
$IBLOCK_ID = 4;
$elementId = 818;
$arSelect = ['IBLOCK_ID', 'ID'];
$arFilter = ['ID' => $elementId];
$ibElement = CIBlockElement::GetList([], $arFilter, $arSelect)->GetNextElement();
$ibElProp = $ibElement->GetProperties([], ['CODE' => 'PROPERTY_EN_NAME']);
print_r($ibElProp['PROPERTY_EN_NAME']['VALUE']);
?>

Comment: Вот только когда засовываю эту конструкцию в foreach (список товаров), вываливается ошибка - Call to a member function GetProperties() on bool (0) Ругается на строку - $ibElProp = $ibElement->GetProperties([], ['CODE' => 'PROPERTY_RU_NAME']); . ID товара присваиваю так - $elementId = $basketItem['ID'];

Comment: `$arSelect = ['IBLOCK_ID', 'ID'];` - поля `'IBLOCK_ID', 'ID'` обязательно нужно указывать. `'CODE' => 'PROPERTY_RU_NAME'` - посмотрите какой **Код** свойства, если только `RU_NAME`, тогда `PROPERTY_` не нужен, и вместо `$elementId = $basketItem['ID'];` нужно `$elementId = $basketItem['PRODUCT_ID'];`

Comment: Спасибо что отвечаете. Поверил все что Вы написали выше, в моем коде эти переменные передаются верно. Результат проверки:  arFilter: Array
(
    [ID] => 231
)
 arSelect: Array
(
    [0] => IBLOCK_ID
    [1] => ID
)
 elementId: 231

Comment: Смущает что  $ibElement: : _CIBElement Object (на пустой странице), а вот когда в foreach, то он пустой $ibElement: :